# How to correct Android icon mismatch when using activity-alias to dynamically change launcher icon?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest, android-launcher, android-icons

I've successfully implemented dynamic Android launcher icon switching functionality in my app using multiple activity-aliases with different icons and labels associated with them as detailed in this Chainfire blog post on the topic:

http://www.chainfire.eu/articles/133/_TUT_Supporting_multiple_icons_in_your_app/

And in this StackOverflow answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15249542/1007714

This solution, however, only works for the launcher icon found in the app tray and on the homescreen. The problem I now have is that the icon used at the OS level (such as for multi-tasking, the uninstall popup, or the Application Manager listing) remains the original or becomes the default generic Android icon if you haven't set one at the application level in the manifest.

Has anyone found a solution to this, or does everyone who uses this solution just tolerate a mismatch (or absence) in the icon at the OS level?