# How to build an Application for different Companies/Users

Tags: c#, android, ios, .net, xamarin

I developed an application with Xamarin, for both iOS and Android.
I want to give this application to 2 companies, each one of them has different needs, so they need to have different features and a different logo and name.

For example, given `CompanyA` and `CompanyB`, `CompanyA` wants to call the app:"Application A" meanwhile `CompanyB` wants to call it "Application B" and obviously each ones with different icons. Also CompanyA wants the mapFeature, while CompanyB want to have a list of number(example of random thing) and CompanyA doesn't.

I want to compile this application like if it was modular, I thought to create a `BaseAppSettings` class, like this:

```
public class BaseAppSettings{
        private String _appTitle;
        private String _appIcon; //path to icon maybe?
        private boolean _mapFeature; // if true I'll do something like #if (_mapFeature == true ) addMap;
        other parameters;
}
```

From which I'll derivate different class for each Company that will use the app setting for each ones the feature and the parameter that they want.

Is this a correct way or a best-practice to do this? I wasn't able to find anything even if I find this very relevant to maximize the reusability of my code.

Hoping to be clear enough, thank you for your time

Comment: Mmmm..Like this yeah, but imagine that tomorrow maybe also CompanyA wants the list.... So that way it's easier to have something that will let me to   Enable it... Also I didn't write that besides from some feature, the app is 80% the same

Answer (score 0):

I urge to follow your approach, it's the correct way.

You need to keep your **CORE** same for any company. What you should offer are components/features/add-ons which customers could request or buy.

Customizing using some class like base settings is okay, but remember to verify them with database side/server side. This will enable your security perspective.

Comment: Yeah it's exactly why I need to have the same app for different companies...So, when I'm adding a feature to the app, should I use `#if ` and check if the feature is enabled or not?

Comment: Checking for enabled features can be done wither from server side or application side. Choice is yours depending on your expectation.

Comment: Is it not possible to just compile different app? Directly input the features at build time? So that the feature that is not implemented does not exist in the .apk(Android example) ?

Answer (score 0):

use the setting activity in your app from there u can enable or disable the feature. about icon see [How to change an application icon programmatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103027/how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android)