# How to change background color of my android app icon dynamically?

Tags: android

I want to change my application icon color dynamically according to the events such as holi,deepawali.....etc.whether it is possible to change application icon color or not?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103027/how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android

This will solve your query.

Answer (score 0):

Please check [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103027/how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android%20This%20will%20solve%20your%20q)

You can achieve this using `<activity-alies>`

Steps : For short guide

> 1. Define alies for differenct icons i.e. Holi, Diwali
> 2. Programmatically set any one enabled

For detailed answer, check above link

Answer (score 0):

You must first integrate the dynamic color into the application, and then set the background color of the application icon to ?attr/background_color

> MainActivity.java

```
DynamicColors.applyToActivitiesIfAvailable(this.getApplication());
```

> style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Material3.DynamicColors.Light">
```

> res/mipmap/your_logo.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <background android:drawable="?attr/colorSecondaryContainer" />
    <foreground android:drawable="@drawable/logo_foreground" />
</adaptive-icon>
```

> logo_foreground.xml

```
android:tint="?attr/colorSecondary"
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score -2):

You will have to put an updated version of the app in play store with updated icon during festival.

Comment: Then user have to update their application version on each festival

Comment: Yes you can't change the app icon in any other way since its used by application launcher to display all apps.

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103027/how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android .. You can change the app icon