# Is it possible to change launcher icon in android runtime with user selection?

Tags: android, runtime, android-launcher

I want to use multiple launcher icon . what i want that user can change launcher icon with his selection

is it possible to change launcher icon run time?

Comment: i don't think it is possible

Comment: whatsapp+ is giving same facility ...so it is possible

Comment: See if this helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103027/how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking you can not change launcher icon at run time. However there are few workarounds available for this:

**1. Activity alias:**
Create multiple `activity-alias` tags in Manifest for your `MAIN` launcher activity and give a different icon `drawable` to it. You can then choose a particular `activity-alias` via your code as per your requirement.

**2. Install/Uninstall Shortcuts:** This approach won't change the your app's icon however you can update (read re-install) your app's shortcut-icon.

Hope this helps.