# Change Launcher icon on android

Tags: android

How to change launcher icon of android app during run time?
I am getting icon from server and want to change it dynamically.
In shortcut icon its working but menu icon is not changing.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a duplicate [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29936645/is-it-possible-to-change-launcher-icon-in-android-runtime-with-user-selection):

Basically it should be impossible but there is a possible workaround.  You can change your manifest to point at multiple drawables.

> Create multiple `activity-alias` tags in Manifest for your `MAIN`
>   launcher activity and give a different icon `drawable` to it. You can
>   then choose a particular `activity-alias` via your code as per your
>   requirement.

Answer (score -1):

Open your android studio as an android application go to res folder inside res folder one folder mipmap. Inside mipmap two folders are showing ic_launcher and ic_launcher_round. Replace with your desired icon of your application and rename your desired icon as ic_launcher.png.
Path=Android project>res>mipmap>ic_launcher and ic_launcher_round > put/replace your desired icon in both folder after renaming abc.png to ic_launcher.png and abc.png to ic_launcher_round.png. You can find the location from manifest file from the mentioned line> android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" . Press ctrl+(mouse click) you will reach to same location. Change your desired icon and enjoy.