# Replacing image resource in app when paired with bluetooth

Tags: android, android-layout, qualifiers

I have two sets of drawable images (say drawabl1 and drawable2). My requirement is that when the phone is connected with blutooth with any other device, my app should restart and use images from drawale2 else drawable1 by default . I am able to get the acknowledgement of bluetooth connection but i am not sure how to make the app use another drawble images on pairing with other devices .

Comment: Follow this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103027/how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android