# apk create another app after changeing icon,name and upload on play store

Tags: android

I have created android app, In that I need to change its icon and name, because my users has their own clients they have there own logo and organisation name, I need to just change app logo and name so user will upload it on play store

Answer (score 0):

Then just change the name and logo and run the apk once then upload the apk on playstore with the your credentials and Hope it will work properly.

Comment: I dont want to give code to my users, And also user will not going to give me his clients, You have any other solution like create wizard or app will create another app how?

Comment: Go through the codes where u can give user to change the name and icon and app itself changes that :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103027/how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android

Comment: Thank you shivani, I will check this but can you please explain me purpose of shortcut?