# how i can change app icon from api?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make the icon of an android application change through API, how can this work?

api = Web Service

The icon will come through api and want to change constantly

this is my code :

```
 android:icon="drawable_resource_path"
```

Comment: api = Web Service

Comment: Please don't try to explain your question by commenting on it.  If you feel that your question could be enhanced, you should [edit] it to include any additional information.

Comment: Why do you need to change the App icon ?. It would confuse the user. Very good explanation is here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34592230/is-there-any-way-to-dynamically-change-an-android-app-icon-like-calendar-app-doe