# How to make an App icon which shows current time as like a real Watch

Tags: android

In Android, I need to make an App icon as like a watch. That icon shows Seconds, Minute and hour lines as per system current time. All lines are moved as per the current time. Means runnable icon like a real watch. Like as per the given image.

[image]

Comment: [Widgets](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/widgets.html)

Comment: as above: `widgets`, but forget about the change every single second

Comment: Yes, pskink I know there is static icon is possible. But, I need to change it every second.

Comment: You are talking about like Apple clock icon, in Android its not possible with default launchers

Comment: there is no way to have a dynamic *icon*. You can only make a widget.

Comment: than change it every minute, forget about one second update

Comment: any solution you got?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, it's not possible for third party apps, as the app you are referring to is a native Samsung app in which Samsung will have the ability to do whatever it wants regarding it, and will have the ability to control the home screen as it wants, but for third party apps **and as a general case** you can only provide one app icon, and as mentioned here in [this fulfill answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34617982/1638739) it can happen only in a certain way and under certain conditions in only small amount of cases:

> I seem to recall that somebody has a GitHub project that tries to wrap
>   the proprietary APIs of various home screens. IIRC, some supported
>   capabilities included either replacing the app icon or adding a badge
>   (e.g., unread message count). However:
>
> - Only a small percentage of devices will support those proprietary    APIs
> - Undocumented and unsupported APIs, discovered through    reverse-engineering apps, are subject to change and may break in
>     unexpected ways

Answer (score -1):

Using app icon you didn't achieve what you want.for this functionality, you need to create Android widget.how to create a widget and how to add into widget list for that you need to do RnD on it.