# Change Icon programatically from custom location android

Tags: android, imageview

How can I change icon in android app. located at custom location.
for example: I created new package in **drawable** i.e  **drawable/pre_paid_ico** , But I can't access any icon from this location in programmatically way. here is my code

```
        iconView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon);
    int imageId = getResources().getIdentifier(array_ico[0], //icon name from array e.g[bg_icon]
            "drawable/pre_paid_ico",//location of icons
            "package.name.here");  //package Name
    iconView.setImageResource(imageId);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change an application icon programmatically in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103027/how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android)

Comment: In referred link its change icon of app but in my case its for just IMAGE VIEW

Comment: THEN CHANGE YOUR TITLE!