# Can an app icon be programmatically changed post-installation?

Tags: android, ios, icons

For example, once the user launches the app (iOS and Android), s/he selects a local dealer. I would like the app icon to change to that dealer’s branding (or a second one to be added, as is possible with Windows’ pin to start).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103027/how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android

Comment: i dont think this would be possible for iOS

Comment: iOS do not allow this feature.

Comment: This is now possible on iOS, as of iOS 10.3: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/2806818-setalternateiconname

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible for android either. While you can install a shortcut, you cannot change the app's icon programmatically.