# How To Keep 2 Icons for a Single App?

Tags: android, icons

I have an Android app with 2 modes normal mode and aggressive mode . When user selects "normal mode" the app icon should be a "blue icon" and when user clicks on "aggressive mode" the app icon should turn in to a "red icon" .This is To easily indicate which mode the app is working in. Is there any way to achieve this? i have both the icons inside mipmap folder.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This maybe helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103027/how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android

Answer (score 0):

It seems impossible as Launcher can be different between ROMs，maybe you should create shortcuts for each mode;