# How Can Change an Application icon programmatically in android without creating shortcut?

Tags: android, android-icons

I want to change an application icon directly from the program and don't want to create shortcut and update it. Some calender app changes icon everyday without creating shortcut.
I read that can create activity-alias element for each of my icons in manifest. It's work for me but if I want to have 30 icons like a calender then I should have 30 activity-alias element in manifest and I do't think it's a correct way. I also read that this way works differently across devices. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change an application icon programmatically in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103027/how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android)

Comment: "Some calender app changes icon everyday without creating shortcut" -- name any that did not ship with the device, but instead shipped from a public distribution channel, like the Play Store.

Comment: I explained that I don't want to create shortcut and I want to change main app icon. I saw calender on samsung  Note4 device and I think maybe there's a way to do it for all devices in android.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in [smart launcher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qgf0C.jpg).

there is an option in smart launcher to change icon of an app without creation a shortcut.
if you are okay with the smart launcher then this is the way. I don't know any other way to do that.