# How to change launcher icon and icon in Application Manager (in phone settings) dynamically from code

Tags: android, android-launcher

My app had different launcher icon from free and paid version. from inside my free app, user can upgrade to paid version. So, in my case, once the user upgrades to paid, I want to change the launcher icon and the icon in application manager (in settings) from code.

I am able to change the launcher icon but the icon is application manager (in settings) is not getting updated.

I tried to find all over internet but with no help.

Can someone help me with this. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change an application icon programmatically in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103027/how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android)

Comment: @Andy.. Thanks for commenting. I followed the above link to make the launcher icon change. So, my code is similar. But it does not change the icon in application manager in settings.