# Can i use .GIF file as a main icon in application?

Tags: android

- I am trying to develop an application. So how can I use the main icon as a . GIF file? if it is possible. Then how?

Comment: because your question is not in any way about a coding problem (one sign for that is that it doesn't contain any code), it is not well-written and it does not show anything that you have done so far to solve your problem yourself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to Android docs you can't use `.gif` format for your launcher icon

> Launcher icons should be 32-bit PNGs with an alpha channel for transparency. The finished launcher icon dimensions corresponding to a given generalized screen density are shown in the table below.

See this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_launcher.html) for more informations on how to create a proper launcher image.

**UPDATE:**

In case that you want some more informations on this problem you can give a look at this [forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/k7T7lPttyko). Spending a little more time on this I found that some people chose to use "dynamic launcher icons" changing the image programatically ([details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103027/how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android)). I do believe that this won't fix your problem, but this should provide some details on what's happening and maybe some starting point if you have to simulate somehow this behaviour.