# Different icons for same application in Android

Tags: android

My Android application has two style themes. And i am wondering is it possible to set two icons for the same application and switch between them, when user changes App theme? Each icon for one style. Thanks

Comment: two icons for the same application,  where?

Comment: on desktop an in launcher applications list. Not two icons. One application icon which can be changed dynamically, when user is switching between  my app themes

Comment: This could be what you're after? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103027/how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android

Comment: Thanks) But i need to replace my app icon not only on homescreen but also in all apps list in launcher

Comment: check also the second answer of the question linked above, it might work

Comment: Yep) Sounds to be a temporary solution, but this solutions doesn't replace the icon at all, but i'll try it. Thanks!)