# Android Custom Shortcut Badge, is it possible?

Tags: android

i know we can use https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger for showing the counter on the app icon. I wanna show custom shortcut badge on app icon, like showing my own custom icon, For example: showing the buzy sign on app icon to let user know their status without opening the app.

Comment: Do you know any app with such functionality?

Comment: Don't think its possible but this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103027/how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android

Comment: @kuffs thank you..!  I'll try that.. it seems something... just wanted to add that type of functionality on client's app.

Comment: @AleksanderMielczarek nop mate, havent really watched anywhere like that...

Comment: i thought if we can show an integer on the badge, there must've been something to show custom thing..!! i think I may be overthinking this