# How does the calendar app change icon dynamically? (pixel android nougat)

Tags: android

I notice that the calendar app change entry icon every day.
I googled and read this:
[How to change an application icon programmatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103027/how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android) 
Use `activity-alias` or `shortcut` can change app icon. If use `activity-alias` way, calendar need to write 31 `activity-alias` node, horrible! If use `shortcut`, app need two `uses-permission` and maybe launcher show a toast when app try to add a shortcut.
Can I change icon like calendar app? Help!

Comment: actually I am looking for this feature in my app ..did you find any solution to display dynamic app icon without using static activity-alias

Answer (score -1):

It could be your launcher that change the icon every day. You can look at this thread for more information:
https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/43s7sm/google_calendar_live_icon