# Is it possible to have multiple configurable app icons for a mobile app (iOS + Android)?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, icons

I'm designing an app that serves a bunch of different instances. Each user belongs to an instance of the platform and when they authenticate I'd like to change the styling of the app icon to reflect their instance.

Ideally, there would be a generic icon when they download from the app store then once they authenticate we'd show their team-specific icon.

Is this possible?
..on both iOS and Android or either?

The development team is building the app in React Native and exporting to iOS and Android. I'm drawing the icons.

Comment: No idea about android, but iOS 10.3 which was just released added this capability.  See: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplication/2806818-setalternateiconname

Comment: @dan :thumbsup:

Comment: There is no way to do that for android but apparently, there is a workaround, Here is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103027/how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android

Comment: @RohitRamkumar  I like workarounds!

Comment: @dan, I was about to reply "Not possible on iOS" until I saw your comment. You should post an answer with this information. I was unaware of this new feature of 10.3, as I suspect are most other people.

Answer (score 1):

For previous versions of iOS I believe it is not possible but as of iOS 10.3 you can do this using:

```
set​Alternate​Icon​Name(_:​completion​Handler:​)
```

and for android check this: [How to change an application icon programmatically in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103027/how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android)

Comment: So, is this a definitive "yes" 
Sorry for taking forever to mark you response as the answer, the project I was working on got unceremoniously abandoned in favor of just getting the web app done.