# Change launcher icon color at runtime

Tags: android

Am developing and app where by the user will be required to choose and change the theme and I wanted this to change the launcher icon as well. Is it possible?

Comment: I think this might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103027/how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android/15249542