# How to change app icon for background running also?

Tags: android

I changed the app icon, its changed but when I see in background running apps it showing previous icon only.How to change that icon

Comment: [refer this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19593601/2794507)

Comment: @user9449700 Try clear cache of your app or try uninstall & install it again.

Comment: Can you tell/show the way you"ve changed the icon?

Comment: In my project, icons are kept in drawable folder so I insert image into that and I changed that name in manifest file where android icon is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Forgot to change the icon in notification builder that's why it won't change in background.After that change it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
1) Build > Clean Project 
2) File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart
```

Hope will help you.