# how can I include an in app icon picker in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, user-interface, icons, picker

I'm putting together an app that lets users create tags (cooking, tv, shopping, etc.) and I want to allow them to pick an icon to attach to the tag.

I haven't been able to find anything online, I think mostly because I can't word it in a way that is distinct enough from everyone that seems to be having problems with their apps actual icon. But I've seen it in plenty of apps in my day.

Is there any way to implement an in-app icon picker? Preferably a method that doesn't involve me having to individually add 100+ icons as resources in my project?

Comment: may this be what you are searching for?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103027/how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android

Comment: maybe something like this library.https://github.com/mikepenz/Android-Iconics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this "icon picker dialog" at:

https://github.com/maltaisn/icondialoglib

Comment: First, thank you for understanding my question! My other responses here and elsewhere really made me question whether or not I was explaining it properly. 
Second, yes this looks like exactly what I was looking for. Unfortunately, I had already abandoned android studio, and haven't looked back! 

Thanks for the resource though :)