# Is there any way to change the app name and app icon change after an user logging in?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I have a SaaS product and each of my clients want an app which has their name and branding such as app logo etc. Is there any way both in android and ios or in react native to determine the user and change the app logo and name dynamically

Comment: Yes! you can change them using app shortcuts.

Comment: @NickBapu can you please share me a link ?

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1103027/6376080)

Answer (score 1):

You can release multiple apps with same source code by rebranding app details in both iOS and Android such as

1. App icon,
2. App name,
3. Bundle Identifier(iOS) / Package Name(Android),
4. Screenshots,
5. Launch Screen,
6. Custom changes if required any.

**But its not possible to change app icon and app name after its installed in mobile.**

Reff Apple's documentation for iOS app:

> You can change the name of your existing app only when submitting an
>   update of your app binary. If you submit an app name which is already
>   in use within the same geography in which your app is sold, you will
>   be prompted to enter another name.