# Load Application icon from a web server android app

Tags: javascript, java, android, angular, oop

Would it be possible to use an image from the webserver as an application icon. I would like to specify the app icon from an url not as a local file. Or Would it be possible to download an image dynamically from a webserver and replace the current application icon ?

Comment: You cannot change the manifest or the resource in the signed-and-sealed APK, except through a software upgrade.

Comment: You can get an answer from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103027/how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android