# Change android application adaptive drawable?

Tags: java, android, drawable, android-icons

Is it possible to change an application icon directly from the program?
I mean, change `icon.png` in the `res\drawable` folder.
I would like to let users to change application's icon from the program so next time they would see the previously selected icon in the launcher.

Comment: I think there is already an answer for this checkout [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103027/how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean changing the icon shown on the home screen, this could easily be done by creating a widget that does exactly this. Here's an article that demonstrate how that can be accomplished for a "new messages" type application similar to iPhone:

http://www.cnet.com/8301-19736_1-10278814-251.html