# How to change the app launcher icon dynamically

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic3, android-launcher, app-launcher

I want to download the app launcher icon through an API and replace the existing icon with this new one, for both Android and IOS applications. I am using ionic-3 Cordova for development.

Is this possible?

Comment: You can send the new icon through an update if you like. Its not going to give you the native Clock app effect. But you can update the app icon.

Comment: Sure that will work for every update. Thanks for informing.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. The icons are static and cannot be changed in iOS. It's not Android.

Answer (score 1):

Since **iOS 10.3+** it is possible (since 2017), but for Cordova applications (like Ionic) is that it will depend on a specific plugin.

You can try this plugin (only iOS, not Android) [cordova-plugin-app-icon-changer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-app-icon-changer)

Install using:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-app-icon-changer
```

For check support:

```
AppIconChanger.isSupported(function(supported) {
    if (supported) {
          ...
    } else {
          ...
    }
});
```

For change icon:

```
AppIconChanger.changeIcon({
    iconName: "<icon name here>",
    suppressUserNotification: true
}, function() {
     // Changed...
}, function(err) {
     // If failed ...
});
```

For more plugins see: https://cordova.apache.org/plugins/?q=icon

> **Note:** if something is desired you could implement your own plugin (or if you want to create a native application) using [**`setAlternateIconName(_:completionHandler:)`**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/2806818-setalternateiconname)
>
> It is important to check if the exchange is supported using [`supportsAlternateIcons`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/2806815-supportsalternateicons)

After placing the images in the "assets" go to `Info.plist` ([`CFBundleIcons`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/cfbundleicons)) add `CFBundleAlternateIcons` with the items corresponding to the images, as in the example:

```
▼ CFBundleIcons
  ▼ CFBundleAlternateIcons
    ▼ <icon name here>
      ▶ CFBundleIconFiles
```

If you need support for iPad the structure should look something like:

```
▼ CFBundleIcons
  ▼ CFBundleAlternateIcons
    ▼ <icon name here>
      ▶ CFBundleIconFiles
▼ CFBundleIcons~ipad
  ▼ CFBundleAlternateIcons
    ▼ <icon name here>
      ▶ CFBundleIconFiles
```

Example in image for Cordova projects (eg. Ionic)

> [image: info.plist]

---

### Android cordova plugins

So far I haven't found existing plugins that do this for Android, but according to this answer [How to change an application icon programmatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1103027/1518921) (I couldn't test the answers at the moment) it is apparently possible to change the icon.