# How to set app icon using an API in android studio

Tags: android, appicon

I am trying to change app icon dynamically from backend, i don't know if that is possible or not but since we are able to use activity-alias to change icon, this looks feasible.

Comment: hi , use this may be helpful for you 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103027/how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android

Comment: Many Calendar Apps...Dynamically change icon depending on date,I can;t find anything to assist you but, my advice would be to research calander apps and libraries and see if theyhave that function