# Dynamic app name,Package name, and app logo

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a ready application. I want to sell same application to customers with there name, logo.
Hence renaming package , app name, logo is not possible for every time. Is there any option to make these dynamic so than i can handle it faster?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103027/how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android) will help you. Note that shortcut intent actions has been deprecated, check [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON).

Comment: @grabarz121 Thanks for the answer. I have sorted out this issue using [ProductFlavor](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/4.1/com/android/build/api/dsl/ProductFlavor)