# Change App Icon by downloading from server at runtime

Tags: android, runtime, android-package-managers, appicon, android-activity-alias

I want to change the app icons at runtime. I went through the below article:
https://blog.jakelee.co.uk/programmatically-changing-app-icon/
, which talks about using `<activity-alias>` to change the app icon at run time. I tried it and it works. But I want to change the app icon by downloading it from the server. I know, it is not possible to do using `<activity-alias>` as this needs to be set in the **manifest**. I searched, if there is an alternative for this, but couldn't find it. So I want to know whether it is possible to change the app icon, by downloading the icons from the server?

Comment: did you check following answer [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103027/how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android/15249542#15249542)

Comment: @EdgarDavids, I tried it and it works if the icons are bundled within the app. I want to change the icon by downloading it from the server. Using <actiivty-alias> not possible, as it needs to know the icon in advance.