# Xamarin Android, change actionbar icon programmatically

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, icons

In attributes of the main activity I set the actionbar's icon:

```
 [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Icon = "@drawable/icon1", Theme = "@style/CustomActionBarTheme", MainLauncher = true, LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleInstance)]
    public class MainActivity ...
```

Is there any way to change this icon programatically in Xamarin Android? For example, I want to change the icon when a button is clicked.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change an application icon programmatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103027/how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android)

Comment: @FreakyAli Well that's not Xamarin C#.

Comment: @FreakyAli also that's about the launcher Icon. I'm asking about the icon appearing at top of the app.

Comment: @Minimus Heximus You code just to change launcher icon not actionbar icon, so what you want to do? It is [actionbar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/controls/action-bar)

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT I want to change action bar icon to show different states of the app.  the actionbar Icon  is the same as app Icon at first. But I want to change actionbar Icon sometimes.

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT  I found the answer : `context.ActionBar.SetIcon(icon);`

Answer (score 0):

```
var actionbar = SupportActionBar;
            actionbar.SetDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
            actionbar.SetLogo(Resource.Drawable.icon1);
            actionbar.SetDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
```

Comment: SupportActionBar is unknown in my app.