# How does Calendar app displays current date inside Calendar icon?

Tags: android, flutter, mobile, google-calendar-api, appicon

The calendar icon change every time according to the current date, How does this be done?
[image]

Comment: Wait really? Mine is showing 31 and its 14 today.

Comment: is it really happening? I don't show so.

Comment: @ChiragBargoojar, In my app  always changes

Comment: You want to display the current date in your above widget using flutter

Comment: @abdul If you are using the Samsung Calendar app, you should see if you get the same behavior with different home screen apps. If not, then the icon day of the month update is part of the Samsung home screen app behavior.

Comment: @MorrisonChang, is it possible to implement from an application or is this the function of the OS

Comment: It is possible to set dynamic launcher icons from your app , but I don't think plugin for flutter exist yet. You can look into android examples how it's implemented - [programmatically-changing-app-icon](http://blog.jakelee.co.uk/programmatically-changing-app-icon/) , [dynamic-launcher-icon](http://www.codeplayon.com/2020/12/dynamic-launcher-icon-and-name-for-android-app/) , [how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103027/how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android)

Comment: so how does the clock app do it ? must have been dynamically generated somehow..