# How can I change App's Icon dynamically in Android and iOS Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I want to change my app's icon from inside app in Android and iOS. How can I achieve this to my app

Comment: I found this only package flutter_dynamic_icon on pub.dev to achieve this feature.

Comment: Did you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103027/how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android

Comment: any other ways to do in Android and iOS both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [flutter_dynamic_icon](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_dynamic_icon) package can help. For me it worked on iOS

just add it `flutter_dynamic_icon: ^2.0.0` to your project and do some changes accordingly

iOS configurations(I found only iOS):
(If anyone found Android Configs please share with us)

Add icon images (here`.png`)

[image: Add icons in ios project]

Add some lines in `info.plist` ([>> Raw info.plist <<](https://github.com/tastelessjolt/flutter_dynamic_icon#raw))

[image: info.plist]

Dart code sample:

```
import 'package:flutter_dynamic_icon/flutter_dynamic_icon.dart';

try {
  if (await FlutterDynamicIcon.supportsAlternateIcons) {
    await FlutterDynamicIcon.setAlternateIconName("photos");
    print("App icon change successful");
    return;
  }
} on PlatformException {} catch (e) {}
print("Failed to change app icon");

...

// set batch number
try {
    await FlutterDynamicIcon.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(9399);
} on PlatformException {} catch (e) {}

// gets currently set batch number
int batchNumber = FlutterDynamicIcon.getApplicationIconBadgeNumber();
```

### Check this repo out for detailed explanation

### [`flutter dynamic icon`](https://github.com/tastelessjolt/flutter_dynamic_icon)

Comment: Followed this exactly and it does not work

Comment: On which platform you are trying to achieve this. This only works on iOS as of now, Android support is yet to come

Comment: iOS only at this moment.

Comment: What's the error showing up??

Comment: it always hits this - print("Failed to change app icon"); it's never successful in my simulator.

Comment: It does not work in apple silicon emulator Mac machines. Try to run in a real device will work

Comment: Probably added icon files might not be indexed by xcode. Try to add them correctly.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this package I hope it can help you

```
flutter_dynamic_icon: ^2.0.0
```

Comment: It works on iOS but are you sure it works with android as well