# Programmatically change Android application icon and name

Tags: android

Basically I just want to be able to programmatically change the application's name and icon
without it reverting to back the originals.

The main way people seem to be doing it is by using an activity-alias
in AndroidManifest.xml, but that seems to need you to use a different
Main package name, I don't want to have another one, I'd like to be able to
use the same one for both.

And, isn't using an activity-alias just going to temporarily change them?

Is there a different way to enable one and disable the other one without having
to use a different package name?

And is there any other reliable way to programmatically change the app icon and name?
It seems like a lot depends on what OS version you are using.

Oh, and not having to add any sketchy permissions if possible.

This on Windows.

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15249542/12771929

Comment: "I just want to be able to programmatically change the application's name and icon" -- that is not possible, sorry. "The main way people seem to be doing it is by using an activity-alias in AndroidManifest.xml" -- that might change the name and icon of an activity. And, if that activity is a launcher activity, that might change the name and icon of the entry in the launcher's app drawer. It does not change the name and icon of the *application*, such as what you see listed in Settings.

Comment: Okay, that's what I wanted to know.  You are right, I didn't want to just change the Activities icon and name, I wanted to be able to change the applications..  Thanks