# How to change app and push notification icon programmatically

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-manifest, android-notifications

I am working on an app whose users are divided into two categories: students and teachers. The app has default app and push notification icon defined in the manifest file, but I want to change these icons after authentication (after knowing user type) so that the app has different app and push notification icons for students and teachers. Is it possible to do that in Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

app have one fixed icon always and `Notification` is showing it for security reasons - prevents apps pretending to be some other

all you can do is changing launcher icon - this one present on "desktop" or apps menu. use `<activity-alias` tag in manifest, some sample [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103027/how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android) or [HERE](https://proandroiddev.com/activity-alias-in-android-manifest-174622a3f2dc)